# Converting NULL received from query builder into empty strings in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

This is a sample db to illustrate my problem.I have a table in which there are some field (in fact many) that are optional and haven't been set to any default value.So obviously when I do

```
$user =  DB::table('users')
    ->select('*')
    ->where('id', $user_id)
    ->first();
```

gives a NULL for those fields

```
["id"]=>
int(120)
["name"]=>
string(4) "jack"
["email"]=>
string(12) "jack@example.com"
["mobile"]=>
string(11) "+4400123456"
["facebook_link"]=>
NULL
["twitter_link"]=>
NULL
["instagram_link"]=>
NULL
["youtube_link"]=>
NULL
```

which is a problem since I'll be sending this as an json API response and the mobile team isn't really happy to see a null there, they would rather prefer an empty string ('') instead.So would I go about this without manually checking each field like I am currently doing

```
$user->facebook_link = !empty($user->facebook_link)? $user->facebook_link: '';
```

You might say just assign the columns defaults well that can be done but it will take some more time as it's a remote database.Currently my best bet is COALESCE but I am hoping for some tweak in laravel itself that would solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no other way except defined the `accessor` method inside User Model itself:

```
public function getFacebookLinkAttribute($value)
{
  return $value ?: 'default value';
}
```

With this approach, you only need to set once inside model rather than `COALESCE` on every query. But do remember, it will return the default value when you accessing it inside your code.

Another approach would be using the `resources` and `transformer(fractal)`, it might not what you need but it worth to look at it.

Correct me if there is a way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are using QueryBuilder not ORM.

So in ORM you have multiple approaches like casting or Accessors.

```
$casts = [
    'facebook_link' => 'string'
]
```

OR

```
public function getFacebookLinkAttribute($value)
{
  return (string)$value; 
}
```